# How can I access an HSQL DB from a .NET application?

Tags: java, odbc, hsqldb

Is it possible to access an HSQLDB database that is running in server mode from a .net application located on the same computer?  There do not seem to be any odbc drivers for hsqldb (freely available).  Am I missing it?

Sun's jdbc odbc bridge seems to allow connecting to an odbc datasource through a jdbc connection, but I would need the opposite in this case: to be able to create a odbc connection that would bridge me to a jdbc source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Run [H2](http://h2database.com/), which is based off hsqldb. Then, use it via postgresql drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions from Google:

- [Easysoft ODBC-JDBC Gateway](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_jdbc_gateway/)
- [odbcjdbc at sourceforge](http://odbcjdbc.sourceforge.net/) using JNI
- [ODBC-JDBC Bridge Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc/st/odbc-jdbc-bridge-st/) from OpenLink

Comment: The first and third option you list don't meet the (freely available) portion of my question, and the second project is dead, according to their sourceforge project page.  But thank you for responding!

Answer (score 1):

According to their website [hsqldb.org](http://hsqldb.org/):

> **.NET and ODBC developments:**
>
> HSQLDB core developer, Campbell Boucher-Burnet has developed a .NET port of HSQLDB 1.8.x. The development is in its late stages. Other core developer, Blaine Simpson has been developing an ODBC driver for HSQLDB 2.0. This currently works for direct statements and supports Windows and Linux. Code for both efforts can be downloaded from the SVN repository.

So you might want to check their [SVN repository](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/).